# Element INCLUDE is not allowed here

Tags: android

I have edited the structure of my activity.xml and now I get the message

> Element Include is not allowed here

. Do you know why?

In some posts, I have read that it could be due to `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` but mine looks to be correct:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".StoreListActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:context=".StoreListFragment"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <include layout="@layout/store_list" />    <---- ERROR HERE

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list_view"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

        </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `<fragment>` does not contain children in a layout resource, last I checked. If you want those three things vertically stacked, the `<fragment>`, the `<include>`, and the `FloatingActionButton` should all be direct children of the `LinearLayout`.